# Necesito configurar Nginx con dos sitios que corren diferentes versiones de php en la misma ip

Tags: php, nginx

Disculpen las molestias, tengo una aplicacion laravel funcionando correctamente, y otro sistema de facturacion en un php antiguo que necesito colocar en un EC2 de amazon, y tengo dificultades para configurar el nginx, son php de versiones distintas en la misma ip publica del EC2

```
Server{
 listen 80 default_server;
 server_name _;

 location / {
  root /var/www/fac;
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
 } 

 location /prod {
  root /var/www/som/public;
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
 }
}
```

cabe destacar que ya he investigado, y estoy pidiendo ayuda porque no he logrado hacerlo funcionar correctamente a ambos.

Comment: podes probar ponerlos en diferentes ports y accederlos por `ip:port`, onda `127.0.0.1:9000` (default) y el otro en `127.0.0.1:9001`

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es el problema que tenes?

Comment: te da algún error? estan instaladas ambas versiones no?

Comment: si, ambas estan instaladas y corriendo, pero no me muestra nada, solo una pagina en blanco

Comment: versión de nginx? cambia el asunto si pones el root con `/` al final? onda `root /var/www/som/public/;`

Comment: no, sigue mostrando una pagina en blanco

Comment: la version es 1.15.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sintaxis del .conf la veo un poco rara, pero lo principal es ir poniendo las reglas de matching en orden y anidar los location para que sólo los `.php` pasen por el fastcgi.

Te dejo un ejemplo de .conf funcionando con php 7.1 en `/` y php 5.6 en `/v5`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


    location /v5 {
      location  ~ \.php$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
          # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
           deny all;
    }
}
```

**Nota:** tal vez tengas que configurar user y group para usar el unix socket, la instalación default suele ser `apache` ó `www-data`, en algunas configuraciones tendrás que cambiarlo a `nginx`, primero probar el `.conf` asi como está y luego ver los permisos.

**Nota 2:** comentado está la forma de usar `IP:puerto` en caso de usar esta opción hay que especificarlo en el listen de cada fpm y que tengan puertos diferentes

$ sudo nano /etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = nginx
group = nginx 

;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = /run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock
```

$ sudo nano /etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = nginx
group = nginx 

;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = /run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono perfecto! disculpa las molestias o/